# Instead of domain url google is showing the default category for image results

Tags: seo, google-image-search

I searched one of my articles on google. I also see images in the article appearing in search results. However, the URL shown for that image is not my domain URL but the default category slug, in this case, the category is personal-finance.

Here's the search syntax I used:

```
best books on price action trading site:worklifeandmoney.com
```

Please see the image below (I've marked the area with the red rectangle):

[image]

My categories are marked no-index. I'm not sure why this is happening. I would want my domain name shown there instead of the default category slug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue is that in your structured data, which search engines use for enrichment of search results, nowhere is the actual website name mentioned.

I ran your page, https://worklifeandmoney.com/best-books-on-price-action-trading/ through the [Google Search Console Rich Results Test Tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?utm_campaign=sdtt&utm_medium=message). I recommend doing the same as you read this. When the tool is done analyzing, go through the results. The website name - and this is what's supposed to appear next to the little blue Earth icon in your image search result box, not the full URL - is nowhere to be found.

Check out this section:

[image]

In the `isPartOf` section, where the `type` is "WebSite," the site name is your name, not "Work Life and Money." In fact, "Work Life and Money" as a phrase appears nowhere in this result.

Then in the `Publisher` section, you have both the "Organization" and "Person" markup, which is confusing to the crawler. Then the "Name" of that person/org is your name, not your website's name.

Just because you noindexed the categories does not mean search engines can't read them to extract your page's and site's semantic meaning. Google most likely looked at your structured data, decided your website name is not the same as your name, and chose the next best thing, as it saw fit.

Try to fix this in the tool that generates your website's structured data. The site name should be "Work Life and Money." That should be the publisher as well, and the publisher should be an org, not a person. Your name should appear as author only. In other words, to get the correct search result visuals, make sure you're representing your data correctly.

For comparison, search for `"coffee beans" site:welovecycling.com` and see the result for the image URL "https://www.welovecycling.com/wide/2019/03/07/is-it-safe-to-eat-coffee-beans/". Then run this URL through the tool. You will see the differences.